# How to make cursor move to the top line inserted with 2O?

Tags: normal-mode, insert-mode

Using a simple example:

```
h[]ello
```

If I type `2o<esc>`, the cursor will be moved to the last inserted line like this:

```
hello

[]
```

But if I type `2O<esc>`, the cursor will be moved to the last inserted line instead of the first inserted line:

```
[]
hello
```

And the expected result is this:

```
[]

hello
```

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: just move the cursor where you like to have it afterwards

Comment: `%s/fix for/way to break`

Answer (score 2):

It works the way it works. In fact, all builtin commands behave consistently (the last line in range is chosen whenever Vim needs to choose). If you need other functionality just make a mapping.